# Collect row counts into new column - by column-text and resetting counts by group

Tags: python, pandas

I tried different ways and no luck. Grouping causing data reduction and I intend to see the entire data with a new column with the count. Please help.

My Test Data:

```
raw_data = {
    'Date': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'ticker':
    ['AAL', 'AAL', 'AAL', 'AAL', 'AAL', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'],
    'signal': [
        'sell',
        'no_signal',
        'no_signal',
        'buy',
        'no_signal',
        'buy',
        'no_signal',
        'no_signal',
        'no_signal',
        'sell',
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['Date', 'ticker', 'signal'])
df
```

Desired Result:

```
raw_data = {
    'Date': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'ticker':
    ['AAL', 'AAL', 'AAL', 'AAL', 'AAL', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'],
    'signal': [
        'sell',
        'no_signal',
        'no_signal',
        'buy',
        'no_signal',
        'buy',
        'no_signal',
        'no_signal',
        'no_signal',
        'sell',
    ],
    'sell_buy_count': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
}
result = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,
                      columns=['Date', 'ticker', 'signal', 'sell_buy_count'])
result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try Groupby cumsum().cumcount()

```
df['sell_buy_count']=df.groupby(df.signal.isin(['sell','buy']).cumsum()).cumcount()+1



 Date ticker     signal  sell_buy_count
0     1    AAL       sell               1
1     2    AAL  no_signal               2
2     3    AAL  no_signal               3
3     4    AAL        buy               1
4     5    AAL  no_signal               2
5     6    ABC        buy               1
6     7    ABC  no_signal               2
7     8    ABC  no_signal               3
8     9    ABC  no_signal               4
9    10    ABC       sell               1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Much appreciated for your quick response :-)